# Java - outer variable declaration

Tags: java, variables, initialization

For my below example, I want to know when in the script the private variable is instantiated...

```
class Foo {
    private String foo123;

    Foo(String s){
        foo123 = s;
    }
}

public class FooDo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Foo a = new Foo("hello");
    }
}
```

When is the private `String foo123` first instantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String foo123` is first initialized to the default value `null` when the new instance is created. Then, when the constructor is executed, the value of the parameter `s` is assigned to `foo123`

For more details see: [JLS 12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

> Whenever a new class instance is created, memory space is allocated
>   for it with room for all the instance variables declared in the class
>   type and all the instance variables declared in each superclass of the
>   class type, including all the instance variables that may be hidden
>   ([§8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)).
>
> If there is not sufficient space available to allocate memory for the
>   object, then creation of the class instance completes abruptly with an
>   OutOfMemoryError. Otherwise, **all the instance variables in the new
>   object**, including those declared in superclasses, **are initialized
>   to their default values** ([§4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)).
>
> **Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the
>   new object**...

Answer (score 1):

`foo123` is assigned when the constructor is first called. However the actual String is first instantiated when it is first referenced i.e. when you refer to `"hello"`. At this time the string is looked up in the String intern table and a entry is created if no such string exists.

Answer (score 1):

String "hello" will be created at the line `Foo a = new Foo("hello");` or if it already present in the string literal pool then the reference `String s` in constructor will point to the already present string and in constructor at line `foo123 = s;`, `foo123` will start pointing to the `String Hello`. So it gets initialized at that place.